# xml-file as input for webservice

Tags: xml, etl

For a customer I developed following 2 processes:

- ETL-process in kettle:

  - Input: xml-file
  - Output: mysql-database
- R-process:

  - Input: mysql-database (created by the ETL-process off course)
  - Output: xml-file
    Now the customer is requesting to ‘package’ this in a webservice. So I would need a webservice that:
- Accepts an xml file as input parameter
- Drops the xml-file on a location on the server where it can be read by the etl-process
- Receives the output-xml from the R-process
- Sends the output-xml back to the customer’s application

I’m pretty new to webservices, is this something that is feasible in any way, or is it generally a bad idea. If it’s feasible, could you give me some pointers on how to get started with this?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards